# jquery - add css rule to iframe body

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I have an iframe and I want to add a css rule to it via jquery. I tried normal jquery `css()` method in this way:

```
$("iframe>body").css("font-family", "Tahoma");
```

But, this does not have any effect. I think this code can add an inline style tag to the iframe body, but not wroked. Also I tried with css:

```
iframe>body
{
    font-family: Tahoma !important;
}
```

But not worked too.

Is there any mistake in my code? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yes, this is an inline iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery if the iframe on same host. Try this:-

```
$('#yourIframe').contents().find('body').css({
   background-color: '#333333' 
});
```